# Binding Validation.ErrorTemplate in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a user control that has a textbox where its text property is bound to a dependency property called SelectedValue.  When the user enters text, that value is validated against another DP called ItemsSource to see if it in there.  If not, I throws an error.  Everything works - the TB in the UC has the default red box around it when there is an error.

But I would like the user to be able to specify a ControlTemplate in XAML when creating an instance of the UC.  So I thought I could create another DP of type ControlTemplate and they could bind to.  This seems to work but how do I actually implement that in XAML?  If it do something like:

```
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{Binding ValidationTemplate}"
```

it throws an error saying "'ErrorTemplate' property cannot be data-bound.".  Below are the relevant parts of the code:

```
<Canvas DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    ....
    <TextBox x:Name="ValueTextBox"
             TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
             GotFocus="_ValueTextBox_GotFocus"
             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
       ----->Validation.ErrorTemplate="{Binding ValidationTemplate}"<-----
             >

        <TextBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="UniqueNamesList" Source="{Binding ItemsSource}" />
        </TextBox.Resources>

        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="SelectedValue" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <l:InListValidator ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" 
                                       IgnoreCase="True" 
                                       UniqueNames="{StaticResource UniqueNamesList}" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    ....
</Canvas>
```

and the DP itself:

```
public object ValidationTemplate
{
    get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(ValidationTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValidationTemplateProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ValidationTemplate"
                                , typeof(ControlTemplate)
                                , typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox)
                                , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ControlTemplate()));
```

Thank for any help.

Ernie

---

**Update:**

Thanks Guys. I actually tried both Adi and Nit's responses.  Both worked but Adi was closer to what I was looking for with not having to define a template local to the User Control.  Nit's actually runs even if I do not actually create the template and just add the binding but the designer gives an error.  I did have to tweak your code a bit Adi to set it on the TextBox itself:

```
public ControlTemplate ValidationTemplate
{
    get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(ValidationTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValidationTemplateProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ValidationTemplate"
                                , typeof(ControlTemplate)
                                , typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox)
                                , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ControlTemplate(), OnValidationTemplateChanged));

private static void OnValidationTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        AutoCompleteComboBox control = (AutoCompleteComboBox)d;
        Validation.SetErrorTemplate(control.ValueTextBox, (ControlTemplate)e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [`Validation.ErrorTemplate` MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx), you can see that it has the [`IsNotDataBindable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.isnotdatabindable.aspx) metadata property set to `true`, so unfortunately you can't data bind to that property.

I believe you can still handle your dependency property's OnChanged event to set that property yourself with `Validation.SetErrorTemplate()`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ValidationTemplate",
                                typeof(ControlTemplate),
                                typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ControlTemplate(), OnValidationTemplateChanged));

private static void OnValidationTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Validation.SetErrorTemplate(d, (ControlTemplate)e.NewValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do what you want with Binding. ErrorTemplate can be used with StaticResource.

Answer (score 1):

As ErrorTemplate is non bindable, what you can do is to set the Validation.ErrorTemplate with the Resource and in your DependancyPropertyChange replace the Resource key with the updated value.

```
<TextBox x:Name="ValueTextBox"
             TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
             GotFocus="_ValueTextBox_GotFocus"
             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource MyErrorTemplate}"
             >
```

and in dependency property change:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ValidationTemplate"
                                    , typeof(ControlTemplate)
                                    , typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox)
                                    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ControlTemplate(),ValidationTemplateChanged));

    private static void ValidationTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteComboBox control = d as AutoCompleteComboBox;
        control.Resources["MyErrorTemplate"] = e.NewValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define and bind as a static resource:

Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="errorTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="_el" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"
                           Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,6,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In Element:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="6" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplate}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Name" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:MinCharsRule MinimumChars="3" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Note: I've taken this example from WPF CookBook 4.5 Page 232 and it works great.